# Can I replace this For loop using a ForEach

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, code-cleanup

The following code works fine, but out of curiosity I was wondering if I can replace the For loop with a ForEach

```
private static List<SubjectRole> getSubjectRoles(List<ca.payment.simulator.model.api.SubjectRole> subjectRoles) {
    List<SubjectRole> subjectRoleList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ca.payment.simulator.model.api.SubjectRole subjectRole : subjectRoles) {
        SubjectRole subjectRoleStream = new SubjectRole();
        subjectRoleStream.setSubjectRole(subjectRole.getSubjectRole());
        subjectRoleList.add(subjectRoleStream);
    }

    return subjectRoleList;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean with the stream API?

Comment: changing to foreach doesn't make much sense. You should use stream, map and collect for full use of stream API

Comment: Pretty much. I see that I came late.

Comment: When you wonder whether something will work, what is it that stops you from just trying it?

Comment: I'm confused, why are you making a new `SubjectRole`, and then doing `setSubjectRole` (???) with the values from iteration? Are you just trying to make a copy list?

Answer (score 0):

You can but it is not likely to make the code more readable.  With `Stream.forEach()`:

```java
        List<SubjectRole> subjectRoleList = new ArrayList<>();

        subjectRoles.stream()
            .forEach(t -> {
                    SubjectRole subjectRoleStream = new SubjectRole();
                    subjectRoleStream.setSubjectRole(t.getSubjectRole());
                    subjectRoleList.add(subjectRoleStream);
                });
        }

        return subjectRoleList;
```

You could use `.map()`/`.collect()` to let the Streams API manage the `List` allocation:

```java
        List<SubjectRole> subjectRoleList =
            subjectRoles.stream()
            .map(t -> {
                    SubjectRole subjectRoleStream = new SubjectRole();
                    subjectRoleStream.setSubjectRole(t.getSubjectRole());
                    return subjectRoleStream;
                })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return subjectRoleList;
```

To get more concise, you need to somehow combine the instantiation and attribute set to one call (method or constructor).  If there isn't an existing method, you could create a private helper:

```java
    private static List<SubjectRole> getSubjectRoles(List<ca.payment.simulator.model.api.SubjectRole> subjectRoles) {
        List<SubjectRole> subjectRoleList =
            subjectRoles.stream()
            .map(t -> copy(t))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return subjectRoleList;
    }

    private static SubjectRole copy(SubjectRole in) {
        SubjectRole out = new SubjectRole();

        out.setSubjectRole(in.getSubjectRole());

        return out;
    }
```

Comment: You're right, it doesn't look that much cleaner. Thanks for the advice folks.